# Why does the play-services-analytics dependency not include GooglePlayServicesUtil or GoogleApiAvailability classes?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have included the play-services-analytics library like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
}
```

However, when I go to actually import the GoogleApiAvailability class, like the following, then Android Studio will tell me it cannot resolve symbol GoogleApiAvailability. I've tried importing the now deprecated GooglePlayServicesUtil class to no avail either

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
```

My second question would be, what do I need to include in my build.gradle file as a dependency to ensure I can import and use the [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) class without having to import the entire google play services library?

I could be wrong in assuming this, but all indications of my project are pointing to the issue of play-services-analytics not including the GoogleApiAvailability class or the now deprecated GooglePlayServicesUtil.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just upgraded to `8.4.0`. This is very annoying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can see a list Google Play services dependencies here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

If you run `gradlew dependencies` on your project, you will see the following:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
```

The dependnecy, `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'` depends on `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0'`.

For `ConnectionResult` and `GoogleApiAvailability`, you also need: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'`.

Also, `new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build()` is deprecated in favor of `new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build()`.

Comment: Ok cool. I tried a few of the other play services libraries and most of them seem to include `base`. Do you know why they chose not to include `base` in `analytics`?

Comment: @w3bshark So did my answer help you? Are you sure they include don't include basement and not base

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to found files `GooglePlayServicesUtil` and `GoogleApiAvailability` but without adding any other dependency my problem solved
[by this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42062624/4531507)

May helpfull for someone