# GoogleApiAvailability missed with firebase-messaging:9.4.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Declaring dependencies as

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

I get "can not resolve symbol GoogleApiAvailability" message in the activity's  import row

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
```

What is wrong?

- not question's duplicate: Google Play Services are already on the latest version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient; cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262213/import-com-google-android-gms-common-api-googleapiclient-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: check Android Support Repository in sdk is latest ??

Comment: Android Support Repository is rev.38.  Google Play Services and Google Repository are rev.32.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add this line to your build file dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
```

`play-services-base` is the Play Services base client library and is listed in the [Play Services Setup Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Answer (score 5):

I faced same problem but in my case problem solved by just changing the position of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the **build.gradle(Module: app)** file.

Line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

was written at the last in the gradle file. Remove this from here and add it to the top, below the line `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
Like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and click on sync now. Problem solved.

Comment: Moving the plugin line to the top might lead to problems of inconsistencies between dependency versions. That's why it is suggested to put it at the bottom, as stated here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin -> "This step requires that the apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' line be at the bottom of your app/build.gradle file so that no dependency collisions are introduced."

Answer (score 3):

For my case just adding this dependency worked -

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using the latest `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'`, for checking the Google PlayServices Availability you can use `GoogleApiAvailabilityLight`