# Checking for google play services with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

How are you suppose to check for the correct version of google play services with `Firebase`?

The docs say that you should check to make sure the version on the device is the correct version in the app but they dont show an example.

without firebase typically you would use `GoogleApiAvailability` but that is not included in firebase core

so what dependencies do I need to include from google play services?

These are my current dependencies

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
   }
```

Comment: I think you have to use **isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()** method provided by ** GoogleApiAvailability** for now. Firebase doesn't provide support for this. Hope it will be added in future.

Comment: @DeepakSingh yeah so what do I need to import as a dependency for google play services

Comment: You can use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.4.0`

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39604063/4815718